# "Error type null or not an object" in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events

My code works in Firefox but I am having trouble with Internet Explorer. When it executes, I get an error and the program doesn't execute right. The description says:

> clientX is null or not an object.

```
var cursorLocation = new function(){
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;
//This function is called onmousemove to update the stored position
this.update = function(e){
    var w = window, b = document.body;
    this.x =  e.clientX + (w.scrollX || b.scrollLeft || b.parentNode.scrollLeft || 0);
    this.y = e.clientY + (w.scrollY || b.scrollTop || b.parentNode.scrollTop || 0);
}}      document.onmousemove=function(e){ cursorLocation.update(e); };
```

Comment: Your current code won't work at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not do `new function(){...}` in javascript.

There is your error.

---

You **should** be doing something *like* this:

```
var someFunction = function(){....};

var someVariable = new someFunction();
```

Comment: Ok i changed and tried this but it is still not working in IE

Comment: I used ; and now i have error saying object doesnt support this property or method